# Does anyone have a picture of the Lego Club alphabet code from Bricks and Pieces magazine?

Tags: history

Somwtime maybe in the early eighties, I read a Bricks and Pieces magazine with a small panel showing the brick alphabet code and it would be great to have a picture of this if someone has it.

This code used an apparently random brick construction for each letter of the alphabet, and it would be fun to write messages into MOCs using the code, or to see if anyone else has already done it.

Comment: Not to mention that naming pieces with these letters and referencing to this question would raise a couple eyebrows... Maybe you're on to the best way to I.D. basic parts without a paragraph description per!

Answer (score 4):

The code was introduced as a puzzle in the spring 1981 issue and is explained in the summer 1981 issue. (Page 7 at the bottom of the page).

the issue can be found found at: http://www.1000steine.com/brickset/miscellaneous/BricksAndPieces/1981-2%20Summer.pdf

And here is the code:

[image]

Enjoy!

Comment: Nice, but I'm sure that it was two pieces each letter, using a slope and a 1x1 brick.  I'll look through the rest of the archive just in case there is something else that fits.

Comment: Thinking it through, it would have been sometime around the Futuron era, late eighties.  I've checked on bricklink and the sets look right for what I remember from the magazine promotions.